# How to enable `fill-column-indicator` on startup

Tags: emacs, elisp, aquamacs

I am using Aquamacs on OS X 10.9.4. I have the following lines in my `Preferences.el` file
(which is similar to the `.emacs` init file):

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")

(require 'fill-column-indicator)

(setq-default fci-mode t)
```

I use `M-x fci-mode` to manually toggle the column indicator.

How can `fci-mode` be enabled on startup using Aquamacs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should *remove* `(setq-default fci-mode t)`.

`fci-mode` is not global, so you could use a mode hook.  If, for example, your opening document on startup is `emacs-lisp-mode`, you could place something like this inside your `Preferences.el` file.

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (fci-mode 1)
  ))
```

You will need to use a mode hook for each major mode; or, you will need to modify fci-mode by adding a global setting.

For anyone who is interested in looking at the source-code, here is the link to the Github repository:  https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for your help, I would up vote but my level is too low.

Answer (score 17):

Don't put `~/.emacs.d` itself in your `load-path`. Always use a sub-directory.

e.g.: use `~/.emacs.d/lisp/fill-column-indicator.el` and:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))
(require 'fill-column-indicator)
```

This library doesn't provide a global minor mode, but you can make one yourself like so:

```el
(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-fci-mode fci-mode turn-on-fci-mode)
(my-global-fci-mode 1)
```

or toggle it interactively with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `my-global-fci-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Great! thank you very much! You are right, I was being messy with my directory scheme, but I fixed it now. In the end I will probably take a mix of lawlist's and yours - I just don't want the fci-mode to be on when editing latex, but I can define that with a separate statement.

Comment: You can replace `turn-on-fci-mode` in that global mode definition with your own custom function which determines whether or not to enable the mode for the current buffer (it's evaluated for every buffer to decide whether to enable `fci-mode` in that buffer).

Answer (score 2):

With Emacs 27 comes the [`display-fill-column-indicator-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Displaying-Boundaries.html) minor [mode](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27.1.90/lisp/display-fill-column-indicator.el), which [obsoletes](https://github.com/alpaker/fill-column-indicator) the `fill-column-indicator` package. You can add:

```lisp
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (display-fill-column-indicator-mode)))
```

to `~/.emacs` to enable it for `prog-mode` buffers, or:

```lisp
(global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode)
```

to enable it globally. To toggle it, use `M-x display-fill-column-indicator-mode`.