# How to turn on the `fill-column` indicator at startup in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

```
M-x spacemacs/toggle-fill-column-indicator
```

This command can turn on the `fill-column` indicator in Spacemacs, but how to turn on it at start up in Spacemacs?

Comment: to enable it globally. To toggle it, use `M-x display-fill-column-indicator-mode.` Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168912/how-to-enable-fill-column-indicator-on-startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno what that Spacemacs command is, but if you use Emacs 27 or later you have minor mode `display-fill-column-indicator-mode`.  You can turn that on in your init file using `(display-fill-column-indicator-mode)`.

If you have an older Emacs release you can use library [`fill-column-indicator.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillColumnIndicator) from Emacs Wiki.  With that, put this in your init file: `(fci-mode)`.

If your Spacemacs command is a minor-mode function, then you should be able to, similarly, just put its name between parens in your init file, to turn the mode on.

Comment: `M-x customize`, then search `display-fill-column-indicator` in it, There is an option called global display fill column indicator mode. Just open and save for future sessions. Thanks.